# Access Perl variable with it's package name in scalar

Tags: perl

It is possible in perl to call method using package name in variable like this:

```
my $cls = 'PackageName';
$cls->method()
```

which calls `PackageName->method()`

What is the correct syntax to use package variable, e. g. `$PackageName::SOME_VAR` in the same manner, having package name in `$cls` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the following syntax.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

package Foo;
our $bar = 123;

package main;
{
    my $package = 'Foo';
    no strict 'refs';
    say ${"${package}::bar"};
}
```

The outer `${ ... }` is for the reference. The syntax says take the value in the symbol table with the given name as a scalar. The inner `${package}` is just the lexical variable `$package`, with the curly braces `{}` as a name delimiter.

It's important to turn off strict references for it to work. Remember to do that in the smallest scope possible.

Comment: Are symbolic references the ONLY way to do it? Isn't there some nicer way like with methods?

Comment: @vvch one other way would be to use string `eval`. Of course you **don't want to do that**. `my $val = eval "${package}::bar"`

Comment: @simbabque You don't want to do string `eval` on a tainted variable. Otherwise, it doesn't matter. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode